# fontspec throwing error with lualatex - broken?

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I get an error when I try to include the fontspec package. Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to compile this using the following build command:
`lualatex --file-line-error-style "%f"`.
Part of the output that I get is:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty:100: Font \EU2/lmr/m/n/
10=file:lmroman10-regular:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric
data not found or bad.
<to be read again>
relax
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
?
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty:100: Emergency stop.
<to be read again>
relax
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
 269 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 rule, 1 kern, 1 attribute, 41 glue_spec, 1 attribute_list, 2 if_st
ack, 1 write, 1 dir nodes
   avail lists: 2:8,3:1,4:1,6:2,9:2
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty:100:  ==> Fatal error o
ccurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I would greatly appreciate any insight that you may have on this issue. I am using Linux Mint 16, with the standard texlive-luatex available in the repositories. Thank you.

Edit: upon request from user phg, here is the output from `luaotfload-tool --version`

```
luaotfload-tool version “2.3”
database version “2.207”
Lua interpreter: stock; version “Lua 5.2”
```

and `luaotfload-tool --diagnose=environment,permissions`

```
luaotfload | diagnose : Loading file hashes.
luaotfload | diagnose : =============== file permissions ==============
luaotfload | diagnose : Checking permissions of /home/alex/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic.
luaotfload | diagnose : Owner: 1000, group 1000, permissions rwxrwxr-x.
luaotfload | diagnose : Readable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Writable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Checking permissions of /home/alex/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/.
luaotfload | diagnose : Owner: 1000, group 1000, permissions rwxrwxr-x.
luaotfload | diagnose : Readable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Writable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Checking permissions of /home/alex/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.lua.
luaotfload | diagnose : Owner: 1000, group 1000, permissions rw-rw-rw-.
luaotfload | diagnose : Readable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Writable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Checking permissions of /home/alex/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.
luaotfload | diagnose : Owner: 1000, group 1000, permissions rw-rw-rw-.
luaotfload | diagnose : Readable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Writable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Checking permissions of /home/alex/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.lua.
luaotfload | diagnose : Owner: 1000, group 1000, permissions rw-rw-rw-.
luaotfload | diagnose : Readable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Writable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Checking permissions of /home/alex/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc.
luaotfload | diagnose : Owner: 1000, group 1000, permissions rw-rw-rw-.
luaotfload | diagnose : Readable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Writable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Everything appears to be in order, you may sleep well
```

Thanks for the prompt feedback!

Comment: Try `luaotfload-tool --update`.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the problems you report. Which TeX distribution do you use, and which version of `fontspec` do you use? (Hint: the fontspec version information should be in the `.log` file produced when you compile your file.)

Comment: Please paste the output of ``luaotfload-tool --version`` and ``luaotfload-tool --diagnose=environment,permissions``.

Comment: @MartinSchröder `luaotfload-tool --update` returns the output:
`luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.`
But running lualatex still returns the same error posted above.

Comment: @castle-bravo Your version of ``luaotfload`` is quite old.
Could you please update your texlive installation?
Normally I’d recommend using ``tlmgr`` for that but you appear to have texlive under your distro’s package manager, so you’re going to have to use that for updating.

Comment: delete the LuaTeX font cache. Should be found at `/ texmf-var/luatex-cache/`  and then run `mkluatexfontdb`

Comment: @Herbert Funny story: `mkluatexfontdb` returns the following output:

`The program 'mkluatexfontdb' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install texlive-luatex`

This doesn't help, since I got my luatex distribution from the default repositories in the first place. Any advice?

Comment: then run `luaotfload-tool --update`. Important is that you deleted your cache.

Comment: Just did. Same output as before, but the minimum working example still doesn't compile.

Comment: I reinstalled texlive-base, texlive-luatex, and texlive-xetex, but there's no change. I will look into removing my entire latex system and installing from another repo. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The one thing that worked was scrubbing my entire system and installing Texlive 2013 from tug.org.

Comment: I just got the same error message. I am using MikTeX and Windows 7. But this time it is user account related: I succesfully compile with admin user but not with another.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have just faced the same problem and it turns out that the solution was to install the `lmodern` package. If I understand correctly this also installs the `fonts-lmodern` package which contains the missing font file `lmroman10-regular` that lualatex was complaining about. (`lmodern` seems to contain font files for pdfTeX)

The conclusion is that this is perhaps not a TeX problem but rather a package dependency problem in the Linux Mint distribution (I am on Linux Mint Debian Edition). Still it seems a bit weird that lualatex requires a font that is not even used in the document.

Comment: Under LuaLaTeX, if no (main) font is specified via an instruction such as `\setmainfont`, the default or fallback main text font that will be used is Latin Modern Roman, 10pt. If a different font isn't requested and if Latin Modern Roman font (family) apparently hasn't been installed correctly, there's actually nothing "weird" about LuaLaTeX complaining that it can't find the font it believes needs to be loaded. Incidentally, even though the `lmodern` package is meant to provide fonts for use by pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX can make use of those fonts as well.

Comment: The thing is the problem happens even if `\setmainfont` is used in the preamble. Could it be that this does not set all fonts for the document (math fonts perhaps?) and thus the Latin Modern Roman fonts are still required?

Comment: Oddly, I still get this error in Linux Mint 18, despite the claim at (bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=853119) that it was fixed in Jan 2017.

Answer (score 21):

You might be missing a required package, try:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-luatex
```

Then, try the update:

```
luaotfload-tool --update
```

Comment: This is the right answer.