# ! LaTeX Error: File `luaotfload.sty' not found

Tags: luaotfload

On Ubuntu 16.04 I noticed that none of the Latex tools will supported other fonts than default. E.g. code like

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Ubuntu Mono}
```

All tools fail with the same / similar message

> ! LaTeX Error: File `luaotfload.sty' not
>   found.

I tried for example Texmaker, RStudio, LaTeXila, SublimeText.

Is it possible to use other fonts when using Latex on Ubuntu / Linux? What are the steps to change fonts?

Btw, when I use a Docker container https://hub.docker.com/r/sumdoc/texlive-2017/ with command

```
luatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode report.tex
```

It creates a document that is garbled beyond recognition. What does work is

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode report.tex
```

But again, this does not allow font changes.

Comment: You can take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161595/fontspec-throwing-error-with-lualatex-broken Also, I have to say that your question could be more clear (You didn't even said that you use lualatex.. You didn't provided a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Also, changing editors doesn't make difference for the compiler you use... But the compiler makes... The last comment because I would suggest to try XeLaTeX too....

Comment: luaotfload.sty is part of texlive so you should have it, update your tex system using your package manager. Note if the file is not there you need to update tex, changing the editor you use will make no difference

Comment: How old is your tex system?

Comment: I am new to Latex; I am as clear as I can be giving my lack of knowledge / experience. I just wanted to try to edit a simple document.

Comment: My texlive looks old. Version shown is 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1. This is what is available in Ubuntu 16.04 repository.

Comment: it is a bit old but it will have luaotfload, but I don't know which ubuntu package that will be in, different linux distributions split texlive in different ways.

Comment: I am using a Docker container https://hub.docker.com/r/sumdoc/texlive-2017/ which has all the required bits. But this turns out to be just a way to run into other problems. At this point as a Latext noob my conclusion would be: forget about it. Latex comes with default font. Requirement is simple enough: another font but practically impossible

Comment: @onknows If you are new to LaTeX I suspect you'd be better off with a 'vanilla' set up? Grab TeX Live from TUG: http://tug.org/texlive/

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this on my Ubuntu installation by doing:

```
sudo apt install texlive-luatex
```

That was suggested to me in a comment to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161595/31839).

Answer (score 0):

Usually if something is not found, I look here --> [Ubuntu Package website](https://packages.ubuntu.com)

Scroll down to find "Search the contents of packages" and then if you type in `luaotfload.sty`, it tells you, that you need to install `texlive-luatex`.

or just do

```
apt-file find luaotfload.sty
```

**Finally you will need to do:**

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-luatex
```

Comment: make that an non-website relying answer and you earn a cookie. btw: if someone has installed the full environment, this shouldn't be an issue. Also, the QO already stated, that 'luatex' was tested and produced a PDF. therefore I see no real answer in here.

Comment: cookie! pls! (updated) also, @naphaneal I just spent the last 36 hours on getting a cv template working and this (my answer) seemed to kill the error for me which allowed me to move on to other errors and finally to a working installation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this package `texlive-lang-italian` was missing. Install it using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-italian
```