# MiKTeX LuaLaTeX broken, probably font-related problems

Tags: luatex, miktex, windows

When I updated my MiKTeX installation (on Windows 7) today, LuaLaTeX went broken. When I try this minimal example it compiles with PdfLatex and XeLaTeX but not LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

I get this error message:

> luaotfload error: "bad argument #3 to 'string.format' (number has no
>   integer representation)" Lua interpreter stack traceback:
>     ...rams/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-log.lua:155: in
>   function <...rams/MiKTeX
>   2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-log.lua:152>     [C]: in function 'string.format'    [C]: in function 'xpcall'   ...rams/MiKTeX
>   2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-log.lua:170: in upvalue 'basic_logger'   ...rams/MiKTeX
>   2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-log.lua:276: in function 'logreport'     ...MiKTeX
>   2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-database.lua:532: in upvalue 'load_names'    ...MiKTeX
>   2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-database.lua:625: in upvalue 'lookup_filename'   ...MiKTeX
>   2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-database.lua:684: in field 'lookup_font_file'    ...iKTeX
>   2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-resolvers.lua:77: in function <...iKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-resolvers.lua:76>
>     (...tail calls...)  ...iKTeX
>   2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-resolvers.lua:247: in local 'r'  ...KTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2019-02-14.lua:29709: in
>   field 'resolve'   ...KTeX
>   2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2019-02-14.lua:29899: in upvalue 'read'  .../MiKTeX
>   2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-loaders.lua:135: in function <.../MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-loaders.lua:134>
>     (...tail calls...)

If I understand it correctly, the main error message is about a syntax error in a luaotfload script? And I guess that it tries to print another error message about some missing font or something?

From [fontspec throwing error with lualatex - broken?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161595/fontspec-throwing-error-with-lualatex-broken) i tried the command

```
luaotfload-tool --update
```

which gave me a similar error message:

> luaotfload error: "bad argument #3 to 'string.format' (number has no
>   integer rep resentation)" Lua interpreter stack traceback:
>           ...rams/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-log.lua:155: in func tion <...rams/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-log.lua:152>
>           [C]: in function 'string.format'
>           [C]: in function 'xpcall'
>           ...rams/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-log.lua:170: in upva lue 'basic_logger'
>           ...rams/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-log.lua:276: in upva lue 'logreport'
>           ...MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-database.lua:532: in upva lue 'load_names'
>           ...MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-database.lua:3332: in fie ld 'update'
>           ...ograms\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts/luaotfload\luaotfload-tool.lua:806: in loca l 'action'
>           ...ograms\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts/luaotfload\luaotfload-tool.lua:1622: in fun ction <...ograms\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts/luaotfload\luaotfload-tool.lua:1606>
>           (...tail calls...)
>
> ...rams/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-log.lua:232: bad
>   argument #3  to 'stringformat' (number has no integer representation)

A similar problem ([fontspec throwing error with lualatex - broken?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161595/fontspec-throwing-error-with-lualatex-broken)) was related to a missing lmodern font package. But I cannot find that package in MiKTeX Console. I have installed similar packages (lm, lm-math, variablelm) but that does not help.

I still guess that the problem is related to the Latin Modern font somehow, because in directory C:\Users...\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\luatex-cache\generic\fonts\otl, where the font cache is, the font listing goes alphabetically and stops at lmsans10-regular.luc.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

If I continue the compilation process by hitting Enter, LuaLaTeX gives a new error message, which maybe can spot the actual problem:

> Font \TU/lmr/m/n/12=[lmroman12-regular]:+tlig; at 12pt not loadable:
>   metric data not found or bad.

The font file lmroman12-regular.otf does exist, and looks fine when I double-click on it in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Standard question with miktex: did you update ad both user and admin using the miktex console?

Comment: @daleif I uninstalled the old all-user installation and added a new single-user version.

Comment: Your error shows pathes related to `...ograms\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts`.  This doesn't sound like a single user installation. If you run a small document with luatex (not lualatex) which contains `\directlua{tex.print(lua.version)}\bye` what do get as output?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: The local MiKTeX folder is C:\Users\magnus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9, hence the path. The output from Luatex is: Lua 5.3.

Comment: Ok, try if it works if you delete (or move out of the tree) the content of luatex-cache\generic\fonts (it can then take some time!)

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Thanks! Just erasing the fonts directory didn't help, but erasing the whole luatex-cache did work, for this problem. (There seems to be more problems too, but that will be another topic...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments.